# How to pass param using query or route through a form?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

```
form(action='/allusers', method="post")  
  input(id='name', placeholder='First Name / Last name')      
  button(type='submit') Launch Spacecraft
```

this is my html(jade) that redirects to allusers page from another page that takes user name as input but i cant pass the 'name' to allusers

```
router.post('/allusers', function(req, res, next) {
var name = req.query.name;
console.log(name);
res.render('allusers', { title: 'all users' });
});
```

Not to mention, i have already tired using `req.param.name`
but it only seems to work with `req.body.name` So i just want to know how to use the `req.param` and\or `req.query` because i cant change my URL from a form submit to extract information from it

Edit1: I kind of solve the issue which was in defining the form and it is suppose to be like `input(type='',name='', placeholder='')` and using `req.body.name` but still i dont know how to play with the URL yet

Comment: See my answer now. At first glance I didn't noticed that you used "id" instead of "name" attribute. That's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I didn't noticed that you are sing *id* attribute instead of *name* which is the right one for defining form field names.

Id is only about identifying any (not only inputs) DOM elemnts in the DOM context. Field names should be specified by *name* attribute. This is why (as I figured out, but you didn't answered me yet), when you submit the form **you don't see "name=xxxx" in the url**.

**Orignal (in this case wrong) answer):**

In GET requests, form data (actual url parameters) come in *req.query* property (not req.params as I said before this edit, sorry).

Fixed example:

```
app.get('/user', function(req, res) {
  res.send('user ' + req.query.name);
});
```

Anyway, see [Express Request.query](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query) documentation.

Actually, according to http specification, url parameters can be provided even in POST, PUT, DELETE or PATCH requests. This is why they come in a different place: Because you always can have url parameters even when submitting your form thought POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH (or any other specified in the future) request.

Comment: When the user push the submit button on formA after filling up his name i want to then show that name on another page. How can i do that?

Comment: Is there any button pressed function in express like we have in .net for example onButtonClick and then we can use all the parameters on that page to save in the database?

Comment: What i mean is : if i hard code the URL into lets say /user/myname and then use req.params.name i can use that name parameter, similarly if i go /user?name=myname in the URL i can use req.query.name. But im confused on how that is going to work when using a button on a form. I hope that clears what i m asking here.

Comment: It seems to me that .net could confuse you very much: Express runs server side and the button exists only client side. Submit buttons, by default, submit forms by (re)loading the same or another page (whatever form's *action* parameter tells). You can change this behaviour client side by jQuery or simly plain javascript. But that is too large to fully explain here.

Comment: Sorry... Now I see I pasted without reading wrong code. I will fix it ;-)

Comment: Okay cool i get what you are saying, you press a button the page reloads and all the information is passed to where the _action_ says... but how can i use that information because my URL does not change so that i can extract the information from it

Comment: Now I fixed my answer. Sorry again. I searched an example in Express documentation and picked the wrong one. Because I used both, query and params many times it didn't seemed strange to me and I thought I were pasting the right code while I didn't.

Comment: I am sure its a silly thing to change in my code but its conceptual and a good answer will be appreciated :)

Comment: What are you experincing? I mean: When you click submit button url changes and contains name parameter in it? Hard coding that parameter in the url works? There can be different issues and I think the actual one is not actually in the code you shown...

Comment: I mean: `var name = req.query.name;` seems correct to me. I was me that I were wrong when checked documentation at first. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Seems correct to me too. But sadly is doesn't work. Look at my code its exactly what I did.

Comment: If you don't answer my questions about your exact sympthoms I think I couldn't help you much more...